# How to run one particular Flutter Project in older version

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

i have multiple project that are running in latest stable flutter version but i want one of my project to run on 3.7.12

i downloaded both latest and 3.7.12 and updated the path of both the versions now all projects are running in latest version ,how can i run one project in the older version

i tried to export the path with in the root directory of the project by entering the command
export PATH="/Users/quiklyz01/development/frameworks/flutter_3.7.12/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

User **FVM** Flutter version management tool for Flutter

For more details visit [FVM](https://fvm.app/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of FVM, as others have suggested, take a good look at [Puro](https://puro.dev).  It's faster, more space-efficient, integrates better with the major IDEs, *and* includes a dart "eval" function and a dart REPL!

I'm a former FVM user, but have been using Puro for at least six months now, and will never go back.

Answer (score 0):

You can either download older version manually and replace that your latest version folder with older version

OR

You can also use Flutter version management FVM

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't prefer using the latest stable version of Flutter.**

You can utilize version control tools that allow you to wait for the latest versions to be updated such as ***labelled in other answers*** such as **PURO** and **FVM**.

By employing version management practices, you can efficiently handle multiple projects simultaneously. This ensures proper **Flutter versions** across your various projects.

**If you don't prefer using the latest stable version of Flutter.**

If you're only working on a single project at a time, you may choose to upgrade Flutter to the latest version or downgrade to a specific version using the command "**flutter upgrade**" or "**flutter downgrade [version]**". This allows you to manage the Flutter version based on your project requirements.

For example, let's say you want to **downgrade Flutter to version 2.0.4**. You can follow these steps:

1. Open a command prompt or terminal window.
2. Run the command "**flutter downgrade 2.0.4**".

This command will initiate the downgrade process and switch your Flutter installation to version 2.0.4.